# Replacing Dimmer Switch

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace a dimmer switch with a standard on off switch. The current dimmer has 2 black wires connected to it but no ground. Do I just unscrew the black wires, remove dimmer, and attach the same black wires back to the new switch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if there is a ground wire in the box, you should attach it to the ground screw on the switch.

If there is no ground wire, but the box is metal, you should connect a ground wire from the switch to a screw put into one of the threaded holes in the back of the box, or use a ground clip placed on the edge of the box.

If there is no ground wire and the box is plastic, you can ignore it.

Comment: Gotcha. I am not entirely sure if what I am seeing in the back is a ground wire...as dumb as that sounds. Is it possible to attach a picture on here?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jh9uhrxlzhh0tlt/IMG_3560.JPG?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwhkkuhd9abnl2n/IMG_3561.JPG?dl=0

Comment: @SThomas Yes, the bare (uninsulated) wires that are nutted together are the ground. You need to add a short length of bare or green-insulated wire (a “pigtail”) between that wirenut and the green screw on the outlet. This wire should be at least the gauge of the black wires (look on the insulation for markings), probably 12AWG.

Comment: Sounds good. And just to be clear, this is a 3 panel outlet so there are actually 3 total switches. I'm assuming I would need to add 3 of the "pigtail" wirings, one for each switch?

Comment: Yes. However, in this case, it’s very likely that the existing wirenut will be too small for all of the wires. Either replace it with a larger wirenut or add a second wirenut with a pigtail between them.